# Disable sorting on autogenerated columns in DataGrid in WPF MVVM

Tags: wpf, sorting, mvvm, datagrid

I have a DataGrid in WPF with **autogenerated** columns.

How can I **disable** sorting functionality of all the rows following the **MVVM** pattern?

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" 
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Set **`CanUserSortColumns="False"`** on dataGrid which will disable sorting for all columns.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}"
          CanUserSortColumns="False">
</DataGrid>
```